# Django model field with switching type

Tags: python, django, database

I want to create a Django model with one field being able to store multiple different types of data. E.g.

```
class DataForms(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(default=None)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)

class Item(models.Model):
    NUMERIC = "NUM"
    TEXT = "TEXT"
    BOOLEAN = "BOOL"
    DATE = "DATE"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(default=None)
    ITEM_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (NUMERIC, "Numeric value"), 
        (TEXT, "Text or Characters"),
        (BOOLEAN, "Yes or No"),
        (DATE, "Date and Time")
        )
    type = models.TextField(
        choices=ITEM_TYPE_CHOICES, default=TEXT
    value = ???????
```

In the end the user should be able to choose the type of item he or she wants to create and then add it to the data form. The `value` field should be either a `models.FloatField()` or `models.TextField()` and so on, depending on the choice the user makes.

I thought about creating different types of classes inheriting from the Item class like:

```
class NumericItem(Item):    
value = models.FloatField()
```

And then creating instances of these classes based on the users choices. But it seems to me like this is unnecessary overhead.
Is there a simpler way to do this? Do you have any recommendations how to treat this on the backend-database? I am currently using PostgreSQL, I experimented with MongoDB using djongo but wasn't satisfied.

Comment: Really depends on whether you'd also need efficient querying (in the RDBMS) for the data. If you don't, you can store it all in a plain `TextField`.

Comment: Honestly for the app I'm trying to build this might be sufficient as I don't expect to have more than a couple of hundred entries per instance. But this begs the question how to approach this if you want to keep scalability to larger applications.

Comment: Then you'd have a couple of options – since dates, booleans and numbers can all be represented by a decimal or float field, you should be able to get away with `(name, description, type, number_value, text_value)`...

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `JSONField` using `pip install jsonfield`.

See https://pypi.org/project/jsonfield/ for more information.

Comment: JSON fields are in Django core these days. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield